# AWS VPN: Can't ping customer side with EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, vpn, amazon-vpc

I have an AWS VPN set up, with the tunnel status "UP". However, I am not able to ping anything on my customer's side, and they are not able to ping my EC2 instance.

Customer side has internal IPs that I need to connect to: 192.168.yy.yy1, 192.168.yy.yy2

My VPC has CIDR block of 10.0.0.0/16

My EC2 instance is set up on 10.0.1.161

For the VPN Tunnel: Inside IP CIDR 169.254.xx.26/30

Static routes: 192.168.yy.yy1/32 192.168.yy.yy2/32

Route table entries for the VPC (IGW = Internet Gateway, VGW = Virtual Gateway):

```
Destination       | Target   | Status | Propagated
10.0.0.0/16       | local    | Active | No
0.0.0.0/0         | IGW      | Active | No
192.168.yy.yy1/32 | VGW      | Active | Yes
192.168.yy.yy2/32 | VGW      | Active | Yes
```

I'm only using one subnet on the VPC: 10.0.1.0/24

My questions are:

1. Customer is able to ping 169.254.xx.27, which is within the Inside IP CIDR shown above. What exactly are they pinging?
2. I suspect that I need to setup a network translation so that 169.254.xx.27 is connected to my EC2 instance on 10.0.1.161. But how can I do this?

I'm actually not even sure what Inside IP CIDR represents. Is this address what the customer uses to connect to us, and therefore is not available on my (aws) side?

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: We will need more information to help you - put everything in your question. Review this document so that can see how AWS builds VPNs. The 169.254.xx.27 and 28 are the inside VPN tunnel endpoints. Add to your question the route table entries. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/NetworkAdminGuide/GenericConfigNoBGP.html

Comment: Add the route table for the other side also. The routes have to be correct on both sides. Also, temporarily change your route for 192.168.yy.xx to be 192.168.yy.0/24 and remove the other two entries. The /32 are more specific, but I want to simplify the debugging.

Comment: Have you managed to figure out what the Inside IP CIDR is?